# Any android automation tools that don't require APK signing?

Tags: android, android-testing

are there any android automation tools which don't require APK signing to run? I need to test an app developed by our vendors which are signed by our clients. Our clients do not provide us with their signing keys. The security is in place as our clients provide us with customised SIMs to work with the APKs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android Automation, you have a lot of choices like

1. UI Automator -

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

2. Robotium Android Testing Tool
3. MonkeyRunner Android App Testing
4. Appium

http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?ruby#getting-started-with-appium
5. etc

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. With tools like Robortium you need to sign the APK. The APK I want to test is already signed by our client. If I unsign and resign it then it won't work against their proprietary SIM. The APK will throw an error when launched.

Comment: @ratsstack: While items #2 and #3 require signing, `uiautomator` does not.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at UI Automator but before I do a quick question. Does UI Automator require the app source code etc? Or can I use it with a third party signed APK installed on a handset?

Comment: UI Automator can work with third party app also. ALso check Appium tool ... http://appium.io/

Comment: @ratsstack, Mark it as answer if it helps and close the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys> I will research and get back.